# WrongTypeOfReturnValue exception when using Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, java-8, stream, mockito

I have faced an error related to the usage of Java 8 streams in a combination with Mockito. It turns out that this line causes a WrongTypeOfReturnValue exception while a test is run. But the weird part is that Idea is able to evaluate this fragment during debugging.

```
when(clientConfig_.getStringForEnums()).thenReturn(enumsList.stream().map(Enum::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

After investigation I've found out that that the original reason is related to the usage of Streams with thenReturn() method. After below refactor the test run successfully.

```
List<String> strForEnums= listWithEnums.stream()
                .map(Enum::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        when(clientConfig_.getStringForEnums()).thenReturn(strForEnums);
```

Comment: Can you please paste the specific WrongTypeOfReturnValue exception and trace? Also, is `enumsList` mocked, and is `getStringForEnums()` `public` and `non-final`?